# Почему не подключаются стили на Github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: скрин стилей в html]Открывая страницы через Live server plagin и в обычном виде все работает отлично, но когда залил сайт на Github Pages стили не подключаться, в чем может быть проблема?
Вот репозиторий: https://github.com/Danvarius/project-x
Вот сам сайт на Github Pages: https://danvarius.github.io/project-x/

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: c путями проблемы, попробуй прописать ../css/stylefile.css

Comment: спасибо, помогло, но теперь половина картинок как через img так и через background не отображаються(

Comment: @VanyaDurbala у вас не работает, потому что вы прописываете пути исходя из вашей операционной системы(потому что вы открываете файл html локально, скорее всего), а не так, как это будет выглядеть на сервере. Если вы это всё запустите на виртуальном сервере, к примеру, LiveServer плагин в VSCode, то у вас сразу будет видно, что не работает

Comment: @МихаилКамахин проблема в том что при запуске плагина LiveServer все работает отлично, вот на Github Pages нет(

Comment: @VanyaDurbala вы не правильно прописываете пути. `/path` так нельзя писать. Можно писать только `./папка/файл.расширение` если из текущей директории вы ищете папку. И `../папка/файл.расширение` вот так, если вам нужно выйти из текущий директории на одну папку назад

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, спасибо вам большое, стили заработали, но картинка не прогружаются, как им путь прописать, вот как я пишу: '/image/Png/logo-technomart.png'.

Comment: @VanyaDurbala просто / нельзя писать, я же написал, только ./

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, ты не прав, просто `/` тоже можно писать